# Inserting in map<int, set<int> >

Tags: c++, dictionary, std, stdmap

Why is the following code not inserting elements in the `map<int, set<int> >` ?

(The size of all the sets after executing the following code is 0.)

I am creating an adjacency list in this map.

```
map<int, set<int> > m;
cin>>n;
while(n--)
{
    cin>>t;
    int i=0;
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d",&x);
        set<int> s;
        m[x] = s;
        if(i != 0)
            m[prev].insert(x);
        prev = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your input please.

Comment: Why are you copying an empty set `s` into `m[x]` (possibly something that's already there). Also - why are you never initializing `prev`?

Comment: `i` is 0, `i` is never changed, and you only insert if `i` is not 0. You would have spotted this quite easily if you ran it through a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't ever changing `i` so `i == 0` when it does the check `if(i != 0)`.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you guys...This was one hell of a mistake! xD

Comment: No worries, mate! We've all been there :)

Answer (score 1):

Your variable 'i' is always 0.
And you are only inserting elements into the set if 'i' is != 0